# Skinny war creation for springboot2 REST application

Tags: maven, skinny-war

I have create skinny war for Springboot2 application. When we are deploying to other environments Is there any other better way to move those runtime jars rather than copying jars to server lib folder

Comment: spring-boot in EAR sounds rather "experimental" (to me), but there are resources! [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/sb-multi-module-maven-project/) looks promising/nice.

Comment: Skinny war makes only sense in relationship with EAR but Spring Boot in EAR Context makes no sense for me? Can you explain more in detail what kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you need to copying jars to server lib folder? There seemed to be misunderstanding how EAR files etc. is working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven Wagon Plugin.

The Maven Wagon Plugin it allows you to upload resources from your build to a remote location using wagon.

Example of upload of your resorces.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>upload-javadoc</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>upload</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <fromDir>local.dir</fromDir>
              <includes>*</includes>
              <excludes>pom.xml</excludes>
              <url>scp://your.remote.host/</url>
              <toDir>remote.dir</toDir>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

For more information , you can find in the link below:

https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html